# how to update certificates for rvm

Tags: ruby, rvm

rvm is killing me slowly.

I am trying to find a memory leak in my rails app.  To do that, I'm trying to install scout. To do that, I'm trying to bundle and deploy the scout gem. To do that I started getting this error

```
ERROR:  SSL verification error at depth 2: certificate has expired (10)
ERROR:  Certificate /C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/OU=Root CA/CN=GlobalSign Root CA expired at 2014-01-28T12:00:00Z
ERROR:  SSL verification error at depth 2: certificate has expired (10)
ERROR:  Certificate /C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/OU=Root CA/CN=GlobalSign Root CA expired at 2014-01-28T12:00:00Z
ERROR:  SSL verification error at depth 2: certificate has expired (10)
ERROR:  Certificate /C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/OU=Root CA/CN=GlobalSign Root CA expired at 2014-01-28T12:00:00Z
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'bundler' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
```

According to the docs, since I'm on a mac, I'm supposed to run:

```
rvm osx-ssl-certs update all
```

When I do this, however, it seems to be stuck on ruby 1.93:

```
Selected SSL certs for: ruby-1.9.3-p551
cURL certificate bundle /usr/share/curl/curl-ca-bundle.crt not found
Updating certificates bundle /usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem: Already up to date.
Updating certificates bundle /usr/local/etc/openssl@1.1/cert.pem: Already up to date.
```

Even though I'm on, and have defaulted to ruby 2.3.1:

```
rvm rubies

   ruby-1.9.3-p551 [ x86_64 ]
=* ruby-2.3.1 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.4.0 [ x86_64 ]
```

Needless to say, my issue remains. I cannot install any gems on ruby 2.3.1.   Is there a way to force the ruby version you want to update the certs for?

Comment: there seems to be an issue or rvm on github https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/3886

Comment: https://gist.github.com/luislavena/f064211759ee0f806c88

Comment: @iamcaleberic the link mentioned in that post is now gone. I had found that link and tried implementing the instructions but the result is that patch is no longer available.  I have come to the conclusion that at the moment (January 2018) you cannot install ruby 2.3.1 from rvm.  I gave up and went to 2.4.0.

Comment: you can always try just nuking the old install of ruby 2.3 and getting installing a new one to see how that goes.

Comment: yeah i actually nuked rvm with implode and removed all certs, and then tried fresh, same result.  looks like it's not possible to install 2.3.1 with rvm right now.

Comment: You can always file a new bug on rvm repo and they might decide to look into it...